# How to put session value store into database?

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

I wanted to retrieve session array and put into other model But throws `

> Call to a member function pluck() on array

Controller I used :

```
$orders =  $request->session()->get('order');
$order = new Order();
$order->school_id = $orders->pluck('school_id');
$order->order_date = $orders->pluck('order_date');
$order->time_slot = $orders->pluck('time_slot');
```

How do i access the session data and put into other model?

Here is the response I get when i dd() the session :

```
array:1 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "school_id" => "4"
    "order_date" => "11/25/2017"
    "time_slot" => "10am - 8pm"
  ]
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this,

```
$orders =  $request->session()->get('order');
print_r($orders);
```

if you getting orders of school id array then you can get it by $orders['school_id']; and if you getting std object then you can retrieve it by `$orders->school_id;`
Use as per output of `print_r(orders)`
Then you can store it by

If std object ::

```
$order = new Order();
$order->school_id = $orders[0]->school_id;
$order->order_date = $orders[0]->order_date;
$order->time_slot = $orders[0]->time_slot;
$order->save();
```

If array ::

```
$order = new Order();
$order->school_id = $orders[0]['school_id'];
$order->order_date = $orders[0]['order_date'];
$order->time_slot = $orders[0]['time_slot'];
$order->save();
```

Comment: when i dd($orders) I got the output as array. But when i tried to retrieve the array it throws Undefined index: school_id

Comment: here you getting multidimentional array you can retrive it by `$orders[0]['school_id']`

Comment: you getting your array at index 0 so you have to pass that index

Comment: Thanks brother, Happy coding

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `array_get` helper.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/helpers#method-array-get

```
array_get($orders, 'school_id');
```

Additionally you can use a fallback as third parameter in case the value is not present in the session.

Answer (score 0):

Session holds all data in Array and not Collection. Function pluck() can only be used for the collection.

Try doing `array_get($orders, 'school_id');` as already mentioned by Marc or just `$request->session()->get('order')['school_id'];`

Answer (score 0):

it depends on how did you store it into session, so if you used push, then it will be stored as array.

anyways change your code to the following:

```
$orders =  $request->session()-> pull('order',$defaultOrdersArrayCanBeHere);
$order = new Order();
$order->school_id = $orders['school_id'];
$order->order_date = $orders['order_date'];
$order->time_slot = $orders['time_slot'];
```

UPDATE:

Did you push it to session as so: `session()->push('order', $order);`

where:

```
$order = [
'school_id'=> $schoolId;
'order_date'=> $orderDate;
'time_slot'=> $timeSlot;
]
```

Comment: I did the way you have said before it sends me `Undefined index: school_id` Error

Comment: I used push to store into session, 
when i dd($orders) I got the output as array. But when i tried to retrieve the array it throws Undefined index: school_id

Comment: @User57 Okay, in this case, use `pull()` instead of `get()`. I updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

> Call to a member function pluck() on array

Your `$orders` variable is an array so you can't use pluck. You can do `$order['key']` to access their values. Or as others suggested, use the helper function `array_get`